# Qnap Qsync: how to start the app at boot?

Tags: startup

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 and I have recently installed an app (via the Ubuntu Software Installer) for my NAS called "Qsync" by QNAP, which is working fine.

The issue is that I have to start it manually each time the computer boots.

I have tried to add the app to the startup apps using the Startup Application Preferences but when I click on ADD I am asked to insert a command the call the application, and because I am not a Linux savvy i had to stop there.

I was curious if sombody could help me figure out how to find this command

thanks

Comment: @Nmath: yes, it is qsync

Comment: @user68186: yes, but it did not work

Comment: @user68186: it worked perfectly! thank you!!!

Comment: Please don't put SOLVED in the question title. Click on the gray check mark ✓ next to the answer and turn it green ✅. This will mark your problem as solved, my answer as the correct one, and help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
which qsync
```

It will output the full path for qsync. Try the whole thing in the Starup App.

**If that does not work,** Go to `/usr/share/applications` in Files (AKA Nautilus) and search for `qsync` or `QNAP` until you find a file that begins with one of those terms and ends with `.desktop`.

Open the file in the Text Editor (AKA Gedit) (it will open in "Read Only" mode, that's fine for us) and look for the line starting with "Exec=..." Use whatever is the "..." after the "Exec=". You may need to add the full path to the executable using the trick of the `which` command.

Hope this helps